# Get "Purchase stop" for in app purchase

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, sandbox, storekit

I have created a test user and I sign out from my phone in Settings.
When I try to try in-app purchase in my app with my test account, I get **"Confirm Your Subscription"** which is fine but later I got **"Purchase Stopped"**.

I have no idea which step I have missed. Appreciate anyone who can give me any clue to look on.

Comment: Can you check error code?

Answer (score 0):

Debug applications using a test account.
App Store is a trading environment , any user can purchase applications in this environment, but to pay if you want to test the application in the process of being developed , we can not be in a real Apple store. Apple provides developers with a test sandbox for debugging purchase behavior , it is completely copied the app store trading environment , but in a sandbox environment, we can not use the usual Apple account , but need to use a test account . ( As long as there is an app id, you can add its goods and tested. )
In iTunesConnect homepage can click Manage Users enter the user management page , then select the Test User to create a test account . According to the latest Apple Developer 's gratitude , create a test account must use a real Email address , and password must be compliant , test account needs to be used in the mail after activation . Created here can be used to buy premium account of the application development process , it must be remembered , the account can not be used to test landing real app store and buying behavior in a production environment , or your iTunes account will likely be stopped with . ( Test account can be added by itnunes connect, just add the account information on the line here to note that this account can only be used for our application sandbox testing , not for normal goods purchased ( for example, to buy has been applied inside the shelves goods ) , otherwise Apple will disable the account. )
When we confirm the purchase of a product , we will get a SKPaymentTransaction object inside transactionReceipt is to verify the information (that is, a set of json string ) , we carry base64 encryption , and then follow the format Apple required ( specifically refer to the document ) is sent to the verify address on it. After successful authentication , the information returned inside app store to purchase goods contain specific information that can be used can be reconciled .

After the purchase of goods , our local transaction queue, there will be a new object , the transaction queues are stored on the local hard disk , unless we call finishTransaction, otherwise the transaction object is not deleted. And when the program is opened ( Here we must note, the following will address this in detail below) if the transaction queue is not empty , then we will inform ios transaction queue status updates, we will be processed according to the state of the transaction object.
SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased transaction is successful, then the money has been deducted finished , we want to ensure that the product will be sent to the user
SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed transaction failed for many reasons ( you can view the specific reason for the failure by SKPaymentTransaction.error.code), the most common is SKErrorPaymentCancelled ( user cancels the transaction ) , or did not enter a valid itunes id
SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored non-expendable commodities already purchased , then we have to deal with according to trading success .

If the transaction fails, we can remove the transaction from the transaction queue. If successful , they have to initiate authentication , verification result waiting to be processed . As a result, no more than three , the validation is successful , verify illegal , validation errors. We have to talk about success and illegal trading transaction object is removed from the queue, the validation error is probably the authentication server fails, we should not delete the transaction object , to be back on the program again to verify, until it succeeds or fails